# Enqueue array[] with different elements

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do is:

```
private Queue<Array[]> queue = new Queue<Array[]>(10);
queue.Enqueue({ bufferarray, networkstream});
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible, if I use 2 queues with same parameters and always call them after each other will I always pull matching values?

Edit for clarification im trying to equeue the received bytes of a tcp stream and the tcp stream itself into one queue or in 2 different queues if I will dequeue matching values

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't compile, so doing specifically that is not possible. However, it's very unclear what exactly you are trying to *achieve*. Please can you update your question to explain what you are trying to achieve, and we can probably help you.

Comment: *I'm not sure if this is even possible, if I use 2 queues with same parameters and always call them after each other will I always pull matching values?* Huh? I'm sorry but I can't make any sense of what you are asking here, all the more because the code you've posted doesn't even compile. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: That said, I strongly suspect that `Queue<Array[]>` is doing something quite different than what you are expecting.

Comment: My bad I posted a clarification

Comment: `Queue<Array[]>` so you want a queue of arrays of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 queues with same parameters and always enqueue the values on both. You can pull them both and they will match with no problem because they function the same. You always get the oldest element of the queue
.

Comment: The funny thing here is that since the OP enqueues reference type objects, the objects they'll get by dequeuing will not just match - it will be the same object.

Comment: Yes, you are right. They will match because they are the same. I am having trouble to understand the real question.

Comment: So If I make 2 queues with the same parameters where one is holding a network stream and the other holding a tcp array response they will match or not?

Comment: Putting that way, yes.